# What is this shrub-looking plant with large pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw this flower while walking outside and would be really interested in growing it in my garden. Could anyone give me the name for them!

[image: flower]

Comment: What's the location? Knowing where it's growing can help narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [Japanese Camellia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_japonica) (Camellia japonica), a close relative to Camellia sinensis, which produces green and black tea.

Apart from long standing garden fame, it has been immortalized in art and literature, e.g. Dumas' [The Lady of the Camellias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady_of_the_Camellias).